# How can I graph domain models from JPA annotated POJOs?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I want to visualize the relationships between all of my JPA annotated classes. Given that I have a folder full of classes, is there a tool that will just scan all the annotations and provide a visualization/picture of all the relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. [Hibernate tool](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) is an eclipse plug-in that has [a feature](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.3.0.M5/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#map_diagram) to visualize the structure of entities and the relationships between them.

[image]